# Abstract algebra: homomorphism and kernel from $\Bbb Z$ to $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

1) Assume that there exist homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_{3}$ where $\ker(f)\neq \mathbb{Z}$? What are the possible kernels? Explain.
2) Lest at least two non-trivial homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_{3}$ whose kernel are not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You should put down what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: My apologies it is my first time posting and I wasn't quite sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\ker(f) \neq \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(1) \neq e$ ($e$ referring to the identity of $S_3$).  Why?

With the above established, we have two possibilities: either the order of $f(1)$ is $2$, or the order of $f(1)$ is $3$.  In the first case, we have $f(2k) = f(2)^k = e^k = e$, so that $\ker(f) = 2\mathbb{Z}$.  Similarly, in the second case, we have $\ker(f) = 3\mathbb{Z}$.

**Examples:**

- $f:\mathbb{Z}\to S_3, f(k) = (1\quad 2)^k$
- $f:\mathbb{Z}\to S_3, f(k) = (1\quad 2\quad 3)^k$

Comment: I'm not sure how to write the latex code in the comment...To answer the why, it think it is because of the property of homomorphisms that says that '\phi(g^{n})=(\phi(g))^{n}' and would in turn make the ker\phi all of '\mathbb{Z}' is that correct?

Comment: For future reference, latex code with `$...$` and `$$....$$`.  For example, `$\phi(g^{n})=(\phi(g))^{n}$` renders as $\phi(g^{n})=(\phi(g))^{n}$.  And yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are subgroups of $S_3$ (of course upto isomorphism) .